# How to change baud rate from 19200 to 115200 for serial communication in android

Tags: android, serial-communication

I am newbie to the android. I am developing an application on serial communication between android and PC here i did some code for sending some data from android to pc serially.But it was working with the baud rate of 19200 but i want it for 115200. I used to put the baud rate  value on control transfer but it wont works for me please help me how to send data serially from android to pc using 115200 baud rate

This is what i had done with baud rate of 115200 but it works for 19200:

```
package com.medeQuip.communication;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

 private static final String TAG = "MedeQuip Demo Communication";

 private static final byte IGNORE_00 = (byte) 0x00;
 ToggleButton buttonLed;
 EditText textOut;
 Button buttonSend;
 TextView textIn;

 String stringToRx;

 private UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbDevice deviceFound;
    private UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
    private UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
 private UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;
 private UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



  textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
  textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
  buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
  buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    final String textToSend = textOut.getText().toString();
    if(textToSend!=""){
     stringToRx = "";
     textIn.setText("");
     Thread threadsendArduinoText = 
      new Thread(new Runnable(){

       @Override
       public void run() {
        sendArduinoText(textToSend);
       }});
     threadsendArduinoText.start();
    }

   }});

  usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
 }

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();

        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            setDevice(device);
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            if (deviceFound != null && deviceFound.equals(device)) {
                setDevice(null);
            }
        }
    }

 private void setDevice(UsbDevice device) {
        usbInterfaceFound = null;
     endpointOut = null;
     endpointIn = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {         
   UsbInterface usbif = device.getInterface(i);

   UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
   UsbEndpoint tIn = null;

   int tEndpointCnt = usbif.getEndpointCount();
   if (tEndpointCnt >= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++) {
     if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getType() 
      == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
      if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() 
       == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
       tOut = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
      } else if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() 
       == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
       tIn = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
      }
     }
    }

    if (tOut != null && tIn != null) {
     // This interface have both USB_DIR_OUT
     // and USB_DIR_IN of USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
     usbInterfaceFound = usbif;
     endpointOut = tOut;
     endpointIn = tIn;
    }
   }
  }

        if (usbInterfaceFound == null) {
            return;
        }

        deviceFound = device;

        if (device != null) {
            UsbDeviceConnection connection = 
             usbManager.openDevice(device);
            if (connection != null && 
             connection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true)) {

                connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0x001A, 0, 
                  new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25, 0x00, 
                   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 
                  7, 0);
                usbDeviceConnection = connection;
                Thread thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();

            } else {
                usbDeviceConnection = null;
            }
         }
    }

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void sendArduinoCommand(int control) {
        synchronized (this) {

            if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {
                /*String text = textOut.getText().toString();
                byte[] b = new byte[text.length()];
                b = text.getBytes();
                for(int i=0; i< b.length; i++){
                 //b[0] = message[i];
                 //Log.d(TAG, "sendArduinoTextb[0]: " + b[0]);
                 usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,b, b.length, 0);
            }*/
        }
        }
    }

 private void sendArduinoText(String s) {
        synchronized (this) {

            if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {

             Log.d(TAG, "sendArduinoText: " + s);


                /*
                usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,
                  message, message.length, 0);
                */
                String text = textOut.getText().toString();
                byte[] b = new byte[text.length()];
                b = text.getBytes();
               // for(int i=0; i< b.length; i++){
                 //b[0] = message[i];
                 //Log.d(TAG, "sendArduinoTextb[0]: " + b[0]);
                 usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,b, b.length, 0);
                 try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
               // }
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
        while (true) {
            request.queue(buffer, 1);
            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) {
                byte dataRx = buffer.get(0);
                Log.d(TAG, "dataRx: " + dataRx);
                if(dataRx!=IGNORE_00){

                 stringToRx += (char)dataRx;
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run() {
       textIn.setText(stringToRx);
      }});
                }
            } else {
                break;
           }
        }

 }

}
```

Comment: use physicalloid library, u can do all sorts of things using this library when communicating with USB devices..